# Quick Pause / Play rather than switching windows

Tags: gnome, playback

I am using Ubuntu 23.10. Often times I have music playing in the background, either via VLC or spotify or some tab playing a youtube video. While working in another window, I would like to hit the windows key and be able to quickly pause playback of the relevant window, rather than clicking on the specific window and finding the play/pause button there. I browsed through the gnome extensions, but didn't find what I was looking for. I imagine some reasonably sized pause/play button appearing in the multi-window view (when hitting the windows key). Does such an extension exist?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up keyboard shortcuts to do that.

Go to `Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts` select `View and Customise Shortcuts` and then under `Sound and Media` select your preferred shortcuts for `Play (or play/pause)` which is a toggle. Some keyboards come with a legend on certain keys as a guide - in my case. my HP English (UK) keyboard shows <kbd>F9</kbd> as the default for this action but you are free to select your own choice.